# Auto fill ForeignKey(User) with current signed in user

Tags: django

I have this model called business I want the foreinkey field owner to get the logged in user name automatically without bringing the dropdown button of all users, I have tried some methods, but it doesn't work. How can I autofill the owner field with the logged in user

models.py

```
class User(AbstractUser):

    phone_number = models.CharField(('phone number'), max_length=15,default='+234',
        help_text=('Field to save the phone number of the user.'),unique=True)
    fullname=models.CharField(max_length=50)
    Affidavit=models.ImageField(upload_to='media/')

class Business(models.Model):

    owner = models.ForeignKey(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE,default=1)
    Phone_Number=models.IntegerField(default='086878432',unique=True)
    Figi_ID=models.IntegerField(blank=True)
```

views.py

```
def details_business(request):

    if request.user.is_authenticated:
        business_form=Business()
        if request.method=='POST':
            business_form=Business_owner_form(request.POST,request.FILES)
            if business_form.is_valid():
                bform=business_form
                bform.owner=request.user
                bform.save()

def dashboard(request):
    if request.user.is_authenticated:
        context = RequestContext(request)
        data = Business.objects.all()
        current=request.user
        print(current)
        context={"obj":img}
        return render(request,'dashboard.html',context)
```

Comment: Can you post your template containing this form?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were supposed to call the forms save method.

```
    if business_form.is_valid():
        business = business_form.save()
        business.owner = request.user
        business.save()
```

Comment: Thank Daniel, but what if I want to get the uploaded image(Affidavit image) of the current signed in user,how can I do that. currently I'm doing this   <img src="{{ obj.Affidavit.url }}" alt="Affi"/> but its not displaying

Comment: Not sure what this has to do with the question. What is `obj`? If you always want to use the current user regardless of the business owner then you would do `{{ request.user.Affidavit.url }}`.